# VRP with parallel relations in Optaplanner

Tags: optaplanner, vehicle-routing

We are trying to solve a VRP with Optaplanner where it is important that two (or more) customers are served at the same time.
This means, for example, that if customer #1 is supplied at 10 o'clock, then customer #2 must also be supplied at 10 o'clock.
It is not allowed to deliver to one customer and leave the other unscheduled.
Such constellations occur with approx 50% of all customers out of a total number of 1000 customers.
It is not sufficient to apply the "delay till last pattern".
All other conditions remain the same as in the VRP example.

How can we proceed in order to solve this problem with Optaplanner?
Are there any examples of such constellations?

Answer (score 0):

In the docs, take a look at chapter Design Patterns, and specifically the **auto delay until last** pattern.

Comment: thx, unfortunately it was not sufficient for us.

R = **Technician**  
A = **Order**  
_same number means same order_  

The following initial situation was created:


**R1** -> A1 -> B1 -> C1  
**R2** -> A2 -> B2 -> C2


Let us assume that the best tour would be


**R1** -> A1 -> C1 -> B1  
**R2** -> A2 -> C2 -> B2  


Any change move that touches only a single order would lead to an illegal solution.  
For instance:


**R1** -> A1 -> C1 -> B1  
**R2** -> A2 -> B2 -> C2  


Which moves can be used (or do we need custom moves) to find the best solution here?

Comment: Custom moves (see docs), I guess. Mix them in with the generic moves - use the benchmarker to figure out the best combination.